# Root access resources for Android

Tags: android, root

I've developed an app which controls certain aspects of hardware via root access. One such control is the soft key backlight. The main issue I'm having right now is working out how to perform the modifications for different devices, for example the following command only works on the Meizu M9:

`echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led-key/brightness`

That turns of the soft keys on a Meizu M9, but not other devices. Different devices have different files in different directories that must be modified.

My question is, is there an online resource that maintains a list of these different files and their locations for devices and their controllable components?